# Converting from word 2010 to 2013 programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office

I'm writing some application on which I will not expand. But the following issue rises:

I need to convert word 2010 file to be in the same comparability mode as word 2013 in C#. How can I achieve such goal?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to expand a bit more: How is C# interacting with these documents? Is this server-side? In the Word UI with user interaction? Something else? It's not possible to give you a targeted "How" without knowing the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

```
Document.SetCompatibilityMode(WdCompatibilityMode.wdWord2013)
```